# Installing libxslt on CentOs 6.5

Tags: python, centos, yum, libxslt

I am trying to install lxml using pip which gave me errors as libxml2 and libxslt were not installed. I tried installing them using yum. libxml2 was successfully installed but nothing happens when I give `sudo yum install libxslt`. The output is as follows

```
[root@motamarri Downloads]# yum install libxslt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: archive.cs.uu.nl
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Nothing to do
```

I am not sure what to do. Plz help. Thank you.

Comment: What does `rpm -q libxslt` say? Are you perhaps missing the `libxslt-devel` package instead?

Comment: This is the output :    libxslt-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64

Comment: Like @EtanReisner points out, the `-devel` variants of those packages  including the C header files are needed to build `lxml`. `yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel` should do the trick.

Comment: I get **No Package available** for  libxslt-devel.

Comment: What does `yum repolist` output? What does `yum search libxslt` output?

Comment: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: archive.cs.uu.nl
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
=================================================================== N/S Matched: libxslt ====================================================================
perl-XML-LibXSLT.x86_64 : Interface to the gnome libxslt library
libxslt.x86_64 : Library providing the Gnome XSLT engine
python-lxml.x86_64 : ElementTree-like Python bindings for libxml2 and libxslt
  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
`

Comment: I had to manually download **libgcrypt-devel, libgcrypt-error-devel and libxslt-devel**  and install  them. Now lxml has been successfully installed. Thanks for all the help.  Also if you can suggest why I could not install using yum, that would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded **libgpg-error-devel**, **libgpg-error-devel-1.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm** and **libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64.rpm** and installed using `rpm -i`. Then I installed lxml using pip. Just posting my work as it may be helpful for someone else. Thank you everyone